# cakephp override construct in child controller

Tags: oop, class, cakephp, inheritance, constructor

I'm wondering if it is possible to inherit/override constructors in child controllers in cakephp.

In my **AppController.php**

I have it like this:

```
public function __construct( $request = null, $response = null ) {
    parent::__construct( $request, $response );

    $this->email = new CakeEmail();

    $this->_constants = array();
    $this->_constants['some_var'] = $this->Model->find( 'list', array(
        'fields' => array( 'Model.name', 'Model.id' )
    ) );
}
```

and in my child controller **SomeController.php**, it inherits the parent constructor

```
public function __construct( $request = null, $response = null ) {
    parent::__construct( $request, $response );
}
```

and when I tried to access **$this->email** and **$this->_constants['some_var']** they both are null. But as soon as I put the code directly in SomeController.php instead of inheriting, it worked.

Did I do something wrong or this is simply not approachable for cake?
Also I tried the same with function **beforeFilter()**, same thing happened.
But it makes sense that each controller to have its own **beforeFilter()**.

Comment: If you plan to overwrite constructors you should first take a look on what you are overwriting there. And how the exact constructor function  params look like... Tip: Typehinting should be respected

Comment: you forget to set it..?? try $this->set method..

Comment: This looks like a horrible wrong mess. There is still an EmailComponent around for that task and doing finds in the constructor is just awkward. This looks like a totally wrong approach, no matter for what it is thought to be used.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't even try overriding the `_construct' function of the appController. That's what the`beforeFilter`,`beforeRender` methods are for. It looks like you are just trying to pass vars to each controller from the appController. You can do that like so...

```
class AppController extends Controller {

   var $_constants = array();

   public function beforeFilter(){
      $this->_constants[] = array('this', 'that', 'the other');
   }

}
```

and in your model's controller you can access the variable like so...

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

   public function add(){
      pr($this->_constants);
   }
}
```

It's a different story if you are trying to send the variables to the view (slightly). Just use the set method

```
class AppController extends Controller {

   public function beforeFilter(){
      $this->set('_constants', array('this', 'that', 'the other'));
   }

}
```

and in any view you can just call the `_constants` variable with `pr($_constants);`. Because it is in the appController it should be available on every view.